# Google Analytics to track converstion from Lite to Pro

Tags: ios, google-analytics

Having the following scenario:
I have two separate apps, **Something Lite** and **Something Pro**, both having analytics.
`User1` downloads **Something Lite** and uses it, when he tries to use a Pro feature, it got prompted to upgrade to the Pro version he then accepted and got redirected to **Something Pro**, he bought it and opened it.

Is possible to know if `User1` bought **Something Lite** and after it **Something Pro**

If so, what should i take care of to get it working?

Additional notes:

1. i'm using google analytics for iOS as an app.
2. I'm not using in-app purchase, at least not for this app at this
   point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of one way you should be able to do this:
Set up Custom Variables, and segment people as users like, for example, "Lite Users" and "Pro User".
Depending on which GA library your using here are two tutorials:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

After that, set up a goal like "Pro download". I don't know how your app is set up, but perhaps you can make it run this code the first time the app is launched. One way to accomplish this could be to load a page that is only visited the first time a user starts the Pro app, and set up the goal towards that page. But there are probably other ways you could do it with your app.
Tutorials for that:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en

Finally, using [Advanced Segments](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2481996?hl=en), you can filter you visitors to only show users of the Lite app, and see how many of those convert into Pro by looking at the Goal you set up earlier.

Comment: I'll try this, but i'm not sure if it will work as expected, as they are two separate iPhone applications, and i'm not sure if GA will recognize as the same user in two different applications.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Well try it out. If not perhaps you can create another profile in GA which tracks both apps in the same place, and then do the above steps. You might have to set up some cross-domain tracking for it to work though: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033876?hl=en